# What invokes _CopyWebApplication?

Tags: msbuild

I've used AstroGrep and searched both `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild`
and I can't find anything that refers to `_CopyWebApplication` besides the file itself. I also tried to search for webapplication to see if something was importing that file, no luck. I have vs2008 and vs2010 ultimate installed.

I'm troubleshooting my override not working.

Where is this target being imported/invoked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the individual project files themselves have the call to _CopyWebApplication embedded. 'C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets' I thought it was going to be part of the default targets that was deciding to include or invoke this target file.

Answer (score 3):

`_CopyWebApplication` target is defined in the file: **C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets**

This target invocation is set by this property :

```
<PropertyGroup>
  ...
  <PrepareForRunDependsOn Condition="!$(Disable_CopyWebApplication)">
    $(PrepareForRunDependsOn);
    _CopyWebApplication;
    _BuiltWebOutputGroupOutput
  </PrepareForRunDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Resulting in this chain of call :

`Build --> CoreBuild --> PrepareForRun --> _CopyWebApplication`

Comment: This particular build script I'm working on is legacy and uses `C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets` which doesn't have the condition `Disable_CopyWebApplication`

Answer (score 0):

I am a team member and we build the project on the server via Hudson , the problem happened to be my version of VS. it seems that VS 2013 is buggy that comments this line in csproj file:

```
<VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
```

I Uncommented it committed on the server . Problem was solved
but each time VS 2013 Comments This line.